# Fill nan with zero python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan, series, imputation

this is my code:

```
for col in df:
    if col.startswith('event'):
        df[col].fillna(0, inplace=True)
        df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: re.sub("\D","",str(x)))
```

I have 0 to 10 event column "event_0, event_1,..."
When I fill nan with this code it fills all nan cells under all event columns to 0 but it does not change event_0 which is the first column of that selection and it is also filled by nan.

I made these columns from 'events' column with following code:

```
event_seperator = lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in 
str(x).strip().split('\n')]).add_prefix('event_')
df_events = df['events'].apply(event_seperator)
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['events']), df_events], axis=1)
```

[image]

Please tell me what is wrong? you can see dataframe before changing in the picture.

Comment: Are you sure those `nan` values in `event_0` are null and not the string `'nan'`?

Comment: Apparently event_0 values was **nan** while under others was **NaN**. I don't know why that happened since I made all those columns the same. So my solution is now:
`for col in df:
    if col.startswith('event'):
        df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: re.sub("\D","",str(x)))
        df[col] = df[col].replace('', np.nan)
        df[col].fillna(0, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 6):

> I don't know why that happened since I made all those columns the
>   same.

Your data suggests this is precisely what has *not* been done.

You have a few options depending on what you are trying to achieve.

**1. Convert all non-numeric values to 0**

Use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

**2. Replace either string ('nan') or null (NaN) values with 0**

Use `pd.Series.replace` followed by the previous method:

```
df[col] = df[col].replace('nan', np.nan).fillna(0)
```